# How does keyword argument work?

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument

I have a piece of sample code:

```
def m(args = nil, **kwargv)
  puts kwargv
  a = args or {}
  puts a
  kwargv['a'] = a
  puts kwargv
end
```

When I invoke:

```
m(args = {'c':'d'})
m(args: {'c': 'd'})
m(args = {xxx}, {})
```

only in the last one will `args` be interpreted as `args`; in the first and the second ones, the dict will be used as `kwargv`.

Is there a more elegant way to specify `args` as a dict?

Comment: __Don't__ use `or` (and its friends `and`/`not`) for conditionals. Here you may think it lets you specify a default value of empty hash, but it doesn't.

Comment: What is dict? ................

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
> m({'c' => 'd'})
# {}
# {"c"=>"d"}
# {"a"=>{"c"=>"d"}}
# => nil
```

The logic behind this is that because the first argument is optional (defaulting to `nil`), and the last argument is a keyword-argument, passing a hash with symbol keys (`m({ :c => 'd'})`) will be interpreted as the keyword hash. Any other type of argument will be passed as the first parameter. If you really need to pass a keyword hash as the *first* parameter, you need to explicitly pass the *second* parameter as well:

```
> m({ :c => 'd' }, {})
# {}
# {:c=>"d"}
# {"a"=>{:c=>"d"}}
```

On a side note, calling the method while naming the `args` parameter (`m(args=something)`) is superfluous, and actually does something different than you think (assigns the `something` to a local variable named `args`, then passing it to the method). Use `m(something)` instead.

Comment: In your first example, the `{'c' => 'd'}` hash is **not** passed as the keywords arguments. Instead, it is passed as a positional argument and is available in `args`. The same is true when passing a hash with symbol keys. If you want to pass only keyword arguments here, you have to call the method as `m(**{:c => 'd'})`.

Comment: About the first part - that is what I say in the answer. I must disagree with you on the second part - trying it in pry (Ruby 2.0.0) passing a hash with symbol keys is passed as the keyword argument hash...

Comment: Hmmm, looks like my tests were off (and OP's method is strange in the first place). You are right of course, with symbol keys the hash, it is indeed passed to `kwargs`. Interestingly, if you pass a hash with mixed symbols and strings as keys, the string keys will get passed to `args` and the symbol keys get passed to `kwargs`. I guess the take away from this is: try to avoid these ambiguities as much as possible when designing method interfaces.

Comment: @Holger Just ,  Python does not have this problem, I need it ..... really.   how can solve this...

Comment: @bryantism - what exactly are you trying to solve? As I say in my answer, to force the hash to be the first parameter, you _must_ add the second parameter to differentiate it. Another option would be to remove the default value for the `args` params, which will make it required, and then it will be chosen over the keyword argument - `def m(args, **kwargv)`

Comment: I simulate the Python requests.get function, def get(url, params=None, **kwargs)  ..... params can be nil .....

Comment: @bryantism - welcome to the ruby language. Each programming language is a bit different, and has its own behaviors and characteristics. I guess that ruby is different from python in that respect. You still can do most things in both languages, but they will probably not look exactly the same...